# Learning loops and lists

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm a Python beginner and I'm currently going through Zed Shaw's course "Learn Python the Hardway"

So, in exercise 32 we are told:

> How do you make a 2-dimensional (2D) list?
>       That's a list in a list like this: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

I did this:

```
# Extra 1
global_list = [[1, 2, 3]]
inside_list = []
for i in global_list[0]:
    inside_list.append(i)

global_list.append(inside_list)
print(global_list)
```

But I’m not entirely convinced that's the correct way. My question is: Is there a way to get the same result without ever leaving the for i in.... loop?

I also tried this, to no avail.

```
global_list = [[1, 2, 3]]
inside_list = []
for i in global_list[0]:
    inside_list.append(i)
    global_list.append(inside_list)
    print(global_list)
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: your answer is in your question

Comment: Are there more constraints?  `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` is completely valid ...

Comment: I don't think OP wants to know how to copy paste `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`. ;) But rather he wants to know e.g. how to build groups of 3 in some range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was "How do you make a 2-dimensional (2D) list?". The answer given was "That's a list in a list like this: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`". Literally, that's the answer:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> print a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

You can also do this:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3]]
>>> a.append([4, 5, 6])
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

You don't need a for loop to append a list inside another list:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3]]
>>> a[0]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a.append(a[0])
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

However, this makes the second element of the list of lists the same as the first, so if you change one you change the other:

```
>>> a[0] is a[1]
True
>>> a[0][0] = 4
>>> a
[[4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3]]
```

What you can do to make a copy of the list is `list(a[0])`:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3]]
>>> a[0]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a[0] is a[0]
True
>>> list(a[0])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a[0] is list(a[0])
False
>>> a.append(list(a[0]))
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]] 
>>> a[0] is a[1]
False
>>> a[0][0] = 4
>>> a
[[4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists can be appended and inserted into a list just like any other object, e.g:

```
outer_list = []
print(outer_list)
inner_list1 = [1, 2, 3]
outer_list.append(inner_list1)
print(outer_list)
inner_list2 = [4, 5, 6]
outer_list.append(inner_list2)
print(outer_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you already went over list comprehension. However, one nice way of doing what you are doing is:

```
>>> global_list = [[1,2,3]]

>>> global_list.append([i + 3 for i in global_list[0]])

>>> print global_list

[[1, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
```